# Jest cannot parse JSX because "support is not enabled", but babel plugin is installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I'm using jest for the first time to test this App component of a React app:

```js
// External deps
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Project-specific deps
import "../index.css";
import App from "../../App"; // Top-level component to be rendered
import {constants} from "../constants.mjs"; // Get general constants of project

describe("Pass props properly", () => {
    test("Check each props mapping.", () => {
        const root = document.createElement("div");
        var props = {
            now: new Date(), // Current date and time
            }
        ReactDOM.render(<App {...props}/>, root);
        expect(App).toHaveBeenCalledWith(props);
    });
  });
```

When I run a custom test, it fails and Jest throws a SyntaxError saying
`Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled` and suggests to `Add @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yd) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.`

However, despite installing the `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` plugin with node & yarn—both as normal and dev dependencies—the error persists. What else I've tried:

- Creating this `babel.config.json` at the project root (I followed Babel's config instructions, except for step #2, [here](https://babeljs.io/setup#installation))

  - `{ "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]] }`

Could it be an improper file hierarchy? Too many installs of the plugin messing with each other? Is there a good way to ensure Babel is enabled/working? Is the issue with Jest's config?

Comment: I haven't encountered same issue but I managed configure jest version as the error log presented... maybe try fix the version of your jest

Comment: I used version 26.0.0 for both babel-jest and jest dependancies

Comment: Note the error suggested adding the library to the plugins array, not just installing it.